# TypeError: district.district(11,) is not JSON serializable for Odoov10

Tags: json, python-2.7, api, onchange

I try to applied domain for many2one type field. But i find following Error:

"TypeError: district.district(11,) is not JSON serializable"

**My Onchange function code is here:**

```
 @api.onchange('district_table_case')
        def _onchange_district_table(self):    
            print "A:", self.district_table_case.district_mainn    
            print "B:", self.district_table_case.district_ss    
            #print "C:", self.district_table_case.district_ss.district    
            rec = self.district_table_case.district_ss    
            res = self.district_table_case.district_mainn    
            print "res:", res    
            for vals in rec:    
                print "C:", vals    
                print "D:", vals.district    
                if vals.district:    
                    return {'domain': {'district_table': [('id', 'in', vals)]}}    
                else:    
                    return {'domain': {'district_table': []}}



district_table_case = fields.Many2one('district.districe.code', change_default=True, default=_onchange_district_table)
```

Answer (score 1):

I got answer for my question.
**Code is below for return domain:**

```
return {'domain': {'district_table': [('id', 'in', [v.id for v in rec])]}}
```